# Vim - Only 1 'bind' in .vimrc file

Tags: vim

I've got problem with .vimrc file. I've installed NerdTree and I added this line into vimrc file:

```
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

It works perfectly, but I want to use python in vim. I added this line:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

And It doesn't work. When I've only had "python bind" it was working, but when I added NerdTree link "python bind" stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

The `<buffer>` in `nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>` means that the mapping is local to the current buffer.

Since you have that mapping in your `vimrc`, it is defined not for the `vimrc` but for the first buffer you edit **and only the first buffer**.

As soon as you open another buffer, no matter what kind of buffer (NERDTree included), your mapping won't work anymore for any other buffer than the first one.

Here is a revised version of your mapping that will only work in Python buffers, all of them:

```
augroup PythonThings
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
augroup END
```

See:

```
:help <buffer>
:help autocommand
```

---

**Never add anything to your config that you don't fully understand.**